# Pycharm Cant locate cPickle on six

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, tensorflow

I'm doing the udacity course on deep neural networks and I'm trying to do the assignment related to notMNIST. I installed tensorflow and six in a virtualenv and then made Pycharm recognise this virtualenv as my project interpreter.

Tensorflow commands can now be run but in this import section:

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
```

both cPickle and url retrieve can not be found.

I updated my six inside the virtualenv, but it seems to be up to date:

```
(tensorflow) Joaos-MBP:~ jantunes$ pip install --upgrade six
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
(tensorflow) Joaos-MBP:~ jantunes$
```

How can I get pycharm to recognise the url retrieve and cPickle libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: Does running `python -c "from six.moves import cPickle"` from command line (inside the virtualenv) work?

Comment: I get no output from it. I'm assuming that means it works?

Comment: Yes. Since it works from the command line, this is not really Tensorflow specific problem. Someone from the pycharm community has to answer this.

Comment: Is there something I need to do to ask them or do I just wait for them to see this post?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm has trouble with resolving names when dynamic dispatch is in play, and their tooltips on such errors say as much. While six manages to map functions to their correct py2 and py3 versions, it does so using dynamic dispatch.

I'm not sure if the problem is a theoretical one or just an issue with the pycharm implementation, but at the very least it is a difficult problem to solve. Essentially, what function gets called is not known until it actually gets called.

One approach you could use to still have pycharm help in these cases is to not import from six initially, and use the version provided by your python natively. Once you're done, all you should have to do is switch the imports from the 'standard' version to that provided by six.

You get used to it.